# SQL 2005 doesn't let me to copy and paste the a big query result, what can I do?

Tags: sql

I am doing a local query through a remote desktop of a server. It is Management Studio 2005 and the result is large. Somehow, it doesn't let me to copy and paste the result.

- CSV format doesn't work since there are some commas in the result which mess up the result when imported to Excel.
- When I copy and paste from the grid, Excel doesn't let me to do so regardless of whether it's a remote windows or my own windows.
- I tired to get smaller result and then copy it piece by piece, but even 2000 results don't work already, just the size like 200 results would be OK, but there are more than 20000 results.

Comment: Instead of copy paste, there might be a way to save your results to file.. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7a3f031c-3579-475d-8182-0321084de1db/save-query-result-at-csv-or-txt-file-from-the-query

Comment: If you have Microsoft Excel installed, you can run import data by executing a query on a SQL server. Take a look at the section `Connect a SQL Server database to your workbook` in Excel's help.

Comment: export works very well!